# Where to hook settings api init

Tags: theme-development, settings-api

I am getting a bunch of notices in Theme-Checker for my settings api init function. The notices are all for 'undefined index' in the $_REQUEST array. Here is the code :

```
<?php

function typesetter_settings_api_init () {

    if ($_REQUEST['update-settings']) {
        typesetter_save_settings();
    }
    register_sections();

    $current = $_REQUEST['tab'] ? $_REQUEST['tab'] : 'page';
    $page = 'typesetter_options_'.$current;

    $callback = 'typesetter_render_settings_field';
    foreach ( typesetter_get_sections() as $section ) {
        foreach ( typesetter_get_settings_fields($section) as $field ) {
            add_settings_field(
                $field['id'], // $id
                $field['title'], // $title
                $callback, // $callback
                $page, // $page
                $field['section'], // $section
                array(
                    'id' => $field['id'],
                    'type' => $field['type'],
                    'choices' => $field['choices'],
                    'desc' => $field['desc'],
                    'class' => $field['class'],
                    'std' => $field['std']
                )
            );
            // Register my setting so that $_POST handling is done
            register_setting($page, $field['id']);

        }
    }

}// typesetter_settings_api_init()

?>
```

I hook this into 'admin-init'. Am I doing something silly here? Do I hook it somewhere else? Should I just ignore the notices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['tab']) && $_REQUEST['tab']) {
    typesetter_save_settings();
}
register_sections();

$current = isset($_REQUEST['tab']) ? $_REQUEST['tab'] : 'page';
```

You have to check for a certain field of `$_REQUEST` (or `$_POST` etc.) before accessing it—or you get warnings.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you and I knew it was something basic like that.